# Does DynamoDB Streams provides a guaranteed stream delivery?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

In case of DynamoDB, whenever we write or update to a DynamoDB table, does it make sure that it will emit the event for that in DynamoDB Stream?

What I mean is, is it an atomic operation to update/write in DynamoDB and send event from DynamoDB Stream? Or it can be possible it writes in DynamoDB but fails while in streaming it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> DynamoDB Streams guarantees the following:
>
> Each stream record appears exactly once in the stream.
>
> For each item that is modified in a DynamoDB table, the stream records
>   appear in the same sequence as the actual modifications to the item.
>
> DynamoDB Streams writes stream records in near real time, so that you
>   can build applications that consume these streams and take action
>   based on the contents.

My take is that, we should not have to care whether the Streaming is atomic or not. AWS provide guarantees "For each item that is modified in a DynamoDB table, the stream records appear"

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html